# Extract keys from a collection and insert in to another collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

| event_time | event_type | category_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-10-01 00:00:00 UTC | view | appliances.environment.water_heater |
| 2019-10-01 00:00:00 UTC | cart | furniture.living_room.sofa |

Above is the CSV file I have imported into the MongoDb. Now I want to extract certain columns(event time and event type) from the existing collection into a new collection, without reimporting them again using CSV file. Is there any query to do it? All I have found on Google is just the copy method, which cannot be used as I only need some of the columns.

Comment: You can use `$merge` for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use the [$out](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage, it exports the current pipeline results into the specified collection, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            event_type: 1,
            event_type: 1,
            // any other structure manipulation we want
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "new-collection-name" // this will repalce this collection if exists!
    }
])
```